# Uncaught error in Braintree hosted fields solution

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, braintree

I am implementing a hosted field Braintree-solution and I am following the documentation very exactly. And the documentation is pretty awesome I must say. Still, I get an uncaught reference error when loading the client. The error appears at the client token. Even though it is set I get an uncaught reference-error there.

Here is the end of the razor-page where the problem occurs:

```
     var form = document.querySelector('#my-sample-form');
     var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
     var clientToken = @ViewBag.ClientToken;

        braintree.client.create({
            authorization: clientToken
        }, function (err, clientInstance) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
```

Here are the methods in the controller (even though I think that is not what generates the problem). Redirected from the post-method which picks up the billing information:

```
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Pay));

        }
        else
        {
            return View(order);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Pay()
    {
        var gateway = GetGetAway();
        string clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.Generate();
        ViewBag.ClientToken = clientToken;

        return View(); 
    }


    public BraintreeGateway GetGetAway()
    {
        return new BraintreeGateway
        {
            Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
            MerchantId = "xxxxxxx",
            PublicKey = "xxxxxxxx",
            PrivateKey = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    };
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePurchase()
    {

            var gateway = config.GetGateway();


            var request = new TransactionRequest
            {
                Amount = 15,
                PaymentMethodNonce = Request.Query["payment_method_nonce"],
                Options = new TransactionOptionsRequest
                {
                    SubmitForSettlement = true
                }
            };


            Result<Transaction> result = gateway.Transaction.Sale(request);
            if (result.IsSuccess())
            {
                Transaction transaction = result.Target;
                return View("Completed");
            }
            else 
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Unsuccessful");
            }

    }
```

Comment: What's the error you're receiving? What reference is uncaught? On what line? Also you might not want to post your payment gateway's private key on a public website.

Comment: I edited the post. It is Sandbox-inloggs but I shouldn't have published them, you are right! Thank's for the suggestion! The error occurs by the clientToken.

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support at https://help.braintreepayments.com.

Are you able to provide the full error message that is being logged in the console?


I would also recommend printing the value of your client token generation value out as well as printing the value of `@ViewBag.ClientToken` to ensure that you are getting the intended value.

Comment: Hi Braintree! In contact with your support I got a clientToken value that I hardcoded into the javascript and then everything loads as it should. How shall I solve this problem? It has to do with the clientToken-creation and I am following your code exactly??